# can't search in list using if in python3

Tags: python-3.x

always search function return bad search string
I'm trying to find if the searching matches the movie_list and print if true or false

```
movie_list = []

def menu():
    data = input(' please type A to add S to seach')
    while data != 'q':
        if data == 'a':
            additz()
        elif data == 's':
            searchit()
        else:
            print('unkown command')
        data = input(' please type A to add S to seach')
        print(movie_list)

def additz():
    name = input('please enter movie name')
    year = input('please enter the movie realsed year')
    movie_list.append(
        {
            'name':name,
            'year':year
        }
    )
    return movie_list
    print(movie_list)

def searchit():
    seaching = input('what are you seaching for boy ??')
    if seaching in movie_list:
        print('okay')`enter code here`
    else:print('bad seach')

menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code for searching()

```
def searchit():
    seaching = input('what are you seaching for boy ??')
    for i in movie_list:
       #print(i)
       if i['name']==seaching or  i['year']==seaching:
          print('okay')
          menu()
    else:print('bad search')

menu()
```

Comment: why did you pass ['name'] from another def ? is it can't use local variable from another def ?

Comment: name is not a variable. its a key of dictionary